# Element UI not working after building project for production in Nuxt Js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, element-ui

I have a Nuxt project ( Universal mode ). When i run `npm run build` and then `npm run start` everything is great except Element ui components are broken.

How i am including element ui in my project?

i have a `element-ui.js` file inside `plugins` directory.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { 
  Dialog, 
  Button, 
  Form,
  FormItem,
  Input,
  Notification,
  Message,
 } from 'element-ui';
import '~/assets/scss/app.scss'

export default () => {
  Vue.use(Dialog)
  Vue.use(Button)
  Vue.use(Form)
  Vue.use(FormItem)
  Vue.use(Input)
}

Vue.prototype.$notify = Notification;
Vue.prototype.$message = Message;
```

I am importing all element ui styles in my `app.scss` like this:
`@import "~element-ui/packages/theme-chalk/src/index";`

and then `app.scss` is included above you can see.

Then in `nuxt.config.js` i have this:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/element-ui", ssr: false }
  ],
```

In development mode all ok.
What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `export default`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'

// Fully import
// Vue.use(Element, { locale })

// On demand
Vue.use(Button, { locale })
Vue.use(Input, { locale })
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but removing export default did not change anything. In development all good but when i build its broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, **I fixed it by removing 'mode' option from element-ui plugin in the nuxt.config.js file**, previously the mode was 'client' I just removed the mode option altogether, Now as we specify no mode, so our element-ui plugin works both on client and server, which solves the issue.

Here's how the code looks like in nuxt.config.js plugins config

```
plugins: [
    { src:'~/plugins/element-ui.js'},
]
```

My plugins/element-ui.js file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI  from 'element-ui'
import {MessageBox, Message} from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(ElementUI);

Vue.prototype.$msgbox = MessageBox;
Vue.prototype.$alert = MessageBox.alert;
Vue.prototype.$confirm = MessageBox.confirm;
Vue.prototype.$prompt = MessageBox.prompt;
Vue.prototype.$message = Message;
```